# Java enum: Return value other than String

Tags: java, enums

I can't find an answer to this question anywhere so I'm hoping someone can help me out. I'm expecting that what I am asking is not possible, but I wanted to confirm. First, an enum example...

```
public enum StatusCode {

    SUCCESS(0), GENERAL_ERROR(999), CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_ERROR(1337);

    private int statusCode;

    private StatusCode(int statusCode) {
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
    }

    public int getStatusCode() {
        return statusCode;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I am using this enum to force specific status codes. My question is this: Is there a way that I can reference StatusCode.SUCCESS and have it return the int value associated with it? Rather than get into too much detail about what I would like to do, take this example:

```
public String getStatusMessage(int statusCode) {
    // Map<Integer, String> that contains status messages
    // return String for key statusCode
}
```

In this example, the syntax for calling this method is `getStatusMessage(StatusCode.SUCCESS.getStatusCode())`.

Is there a way to shorten this to `getStatusMessage(StatusCode.SUCCESS)`?

I think the second way looks much cleaner and would make my code much more readable. Any ideas? Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why can't you just use `public String getStatusMessage(StatusCode status)`?

Comment: Why don't you want to have a `Map<StatusCode, String>` instead?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use `public String getStatusMessage(StatusCode statusCode)`?

Comment: I just meant that as an example. For instance, I may also want to use a setter that takes `int statusCode`. Same problem there, I will have to use `StatusCode.SUCCESS.getStatusCode()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
public String getStatusMessage(StatusCode code) {
    int status = code.getStatusCode();
    String message = ...do stuff to get message :)
    return message;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I should have thought of this :) StatusCode was originally a set of static ints. When I converted it to an enum, I didn't consider changing some of the code around it. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Luckily for you, EnumMap exists just for that situation.

```
    private static final Map<StatusCode, String> mapMessage = 
                         new EnumMap<>(StatusCode.class);
    mapMessage.put(SUCCESS, "Success.");
    ...
```

You don't even need the method `getStatusMessage`, just call `map.getMessage(SUCCESS)`.

However maybe you would be better off adding a `String message` field within StatusMessage and calling the constructors like `SUCCESS(0, "Success")` and then adding a getter for the message.